# Glide sizing the image loaded to an imageview incorrectly when using 9 patch place holder

Tags: android, android-imageview, nine-patch, android-glide

I am trying to implement a 9-patch image as placeholder for the ImageView while using `Glide` library to load bitmap.

When I try to use **9-patch image** as placeholder, the real image is resized to a **smaller size** and loaded onto the `ImageView`. If I use a **regular image** as placeholder, this **issue is not there** and the loaded image will fill the entire `ImageView`.

**Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?**

```
Glide.with(getContext())
.load(imagePath)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.my_9_patch_image)
.into(imageView);
```

*EDIT: Adding layout code*

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout{

    private ImageView imageView;

     public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setPictures(ArrayList<String> listPicturePaths){
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setupImageView();
        setPicture(0);
    }

    private void setupImageView(){

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        this.imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        this.imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(imageView);
    }

    private void setPicture(int index){
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(mListPicturePaths.get(index)).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.my_9_patch_image)
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```

[image: sample screen]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong; Glide does not know what size your image is going to be until it is downloaded, so it does not know how large to display the placeholder.

You would need to specify the width and/or height of your imageView if you know the size, or the aspect ratio.

Comment: The place holder is displaying correctly. But, the bitmap loaded in the ImageView is scaled down (smaller than the ImageView for some reason). If I dont use a 9 patch image as place holder, the bitmap fills the entire ImageView, as expected.

Comment: Glide looks at the size of your imageView and scales the bitmap to fit. You have to set the imageView to the right size, or tell Glide what size you want it to load for the image.

Comment: ImageView is assigned size programatically using LayoutParams. Its size is defined as width `MATCH_PARENT` and height `MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: Can you post your layout and code? You could be requesting Glide to load before the imageView has been measured.

Comment: So you set the imageView to match_parent. This means it will match its parent size - what is that? What is the RelativeLayout dimensions? You may need to set those to a certain value (based on your image) to get Glide to load the right size. You could try to load the full res image, as a test, using override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) in glide.

Comment: ImageView is matching the parent size. Its working correctly, but the bitmap loaded inside is scaled smaller even though its original size is much larger. I have added a picture for clarification. The ImageView size shouldcome approximately to 800x400px

Comment: I haven't used 9-patch as placeholder myself, I'll have to get a test project going. As a temp workaround, you could use a viewTreeObserver and a onPreDrawListener to get the RelativeLaout dimensions, then use override(width, height) in the glide request to specify the right width and height for the image.